# Define another attribute in setter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, rspec-rails

I want to define a **role** attribute in my **User** model when I set a **physician** attribute, to know that now that this attribute is defined the **User** instance has a **role** of *:physician* (as it is an enum).

It *works* as the role is defined, but role is wrongly assigned to another enum type as shown in my RSpec test

```
enum role: [:assistant, :physician, :patient]

def physician=(value)
    write_attribute(:role, "physician")
    super(value)
end
```

RSpec:

```
User is a physician should only be a physician
     Failure/Error: expect(user.role).to eq('physician')

       expected: "physician"
            got: "assistant"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec
```

In fact I tried to replicate this manually in Rails console

```
user = User.new
physician = Physician.new

user.physician = physician
user.physician?
 => false
user.role
 => "assistant"
```

I suspect that *write_attribute* does not work nicely with Enums...

P.D. I also tried with *write_attribute(:role, :physician)* but it sets the role value to nil

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fixed with:

```
def physician=(value)
    self.send("role=", "physician")
    super(value)
end
```

But I'm not sure if it's a good idea to call *send* directly like this

Comment: Why not just `self.role = "assistant"` ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `send` unless `#role=` is a private method. Just call the accessor on `self` directly:

```
def physician=(value)
  self.role = 'physician'
  super(value)
end
```